# why cache is rebuild when it should not be?

Tags: r, knitr

A minimal example is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

<<setup, echo = FALSE>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  cache = TRUE,
  autodep = TRUE
)
@

\begin{document}
<<chunk1>>=
n <- 6
rnorm(n)
@

<<chunk2>>=
n <- 10
rnorm(n)
@

\end{document}
```

Run the code once, the results are cached. When I change the code in the first chunk, say `n <- 10` and rerun the code, the chunk2 is also rebuild. I expect that the chunk2 will not be rebuild since it should not depend on the `n` in the first chunk.

---

I used `rnorm` in above example. As mentioned by @m0nhawk, the two chunks are indirectly related. The following code does not involve random. The problem is still the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

<<setup, echo = FALSE>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  cache = TRUE,
  autodep = TRUE
)
@

\begin{document}
<<chunk1>>=
n <- 6
print(seq_len(n))
print(Sys.time())
@

<<chunk2>>=
n <- 10
print(seq_len(n))
print(Sys.time())
@


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those two chunks are indirectly related by `.Random.seed`.

`knitr` has a support for saving [random seed](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/#reproducibility-with-rng), but it won't work directly.

To make it work, add the `rand_seed` to `opts_chunk` and set different seeds for each chunks:

```
\documentclass{article}

<<setup, echo = FALSE>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  cache = TRUE,
  autodep = TRUE,
  cache.extra = rand_seed
)
@

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
<<chunk1>>=
set.seed(100)
n <- 10
rnorm(n)
@

<<chunk2>>=
set.seed(101)
n <- 10
rnorm(n)
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have removed `rnorm` function. The problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I consider this to be [a bug of **knitr**](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1708), and I just pushed [a fix](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/4d6fc85c3f64b484917bd441840357ef362fda38) on Github. It happened because of an attempt to fix [another related issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1403). On second thought, I decided that the issue you reported should be of higher priority, so your example should work well after you clear the `cache/` directory, and install the dev version of **knitr**:

```r
remotes::install_github('yihui/knitr')
```